# How to query the type of an existing index in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

The pg_index table gives info on indexes, it doesn't seem to have a column describing the index type (btree, hash, gin, etc...)

What is the correct way of knowing an existing index type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access method of an index is defined in the catalog [`pg_am`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/catalog-pg-am.html), pointed by the column `relam` of the catalog [`pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/catalog-pg-class.html), e.g.:

```
select c.relname, a.amname
from pg_index i
join pg_class c on c.oid = i.indexrelid
join pg_am a on a.oid = c.relam
where relnamespace = 'public'::regnamespace;

       relname        | amname 
----------------------+--------
 array_test_arr_idx   | gin
 students_topics_pkey | btree
 images_pkey          | btree
```